# Close modal on AJAX Sucess(ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have Modal in view for making new record in Database.

View for it in Partial View

> Here is code of view

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
```

For AJAX I using this code

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#save_quest').click(function () {
        savequestion();
    });
});
    function savequestion() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            dataType: 'Json',
            data: {
                Question_new: $('#question').val(),
                Answer: $('#answer').val(),
                Preparing: $('#prepare').val(),
                Retries: $('#retries').val(),
                  },
            url: '@Url.Action("CreateNewQuestion", "Questions")',
            success: function (da) {
                if (da.Result === "Success") {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide')
                    //window.location.href = da.RedirectUrl;

                } else {

                    alert('Error' + da.Message);
                }
            },
            error: function (da) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    }
```

I need to hide modal when AJAX call is Successful

I try this `$('#myModal').modal('hide')`

Here is my modal on Primary View

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="false">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Questions/CreateQuestion.cshtml")
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

How I can hide it on AJAX Success?

Comment: your code seems like fine is there any error in console ? check this line by using debugger or `console.log()` `da.Result === "Success"` what it returns `true` or `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try any of the below option  in your ajax success block. Hopefully it will solve your problem.

```
        $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    OR
        $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
    OR
        $('#myModal').removeClass('show');
    OR
        $('#myModal').modal().hide();
    OR
        $("#myModal .close").click();
    OR
        $("#myModal .close").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

Just need to write

`$('#myModal').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

> > This is not the proper way.
> >         $('#myModal').hide();
> >
> > The proper way
> >      $("#myModal").modal('hide');

Have you try adding bootstrap.js in your page? if not please include it in your page and then test. It should work.